# Request result from async function

Tags: javascript, rest, asynchronous

I need the value of the variable '**result**' to make a comparison. Im having problem to get this '**result**' value.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

**Im using node to make an REST application, and I need this to result in my GET method

```
async function get(req, res, next) {
  var result = 0;
  try {
    const context = {};
    const login = {};
    login.user = req.params.user, 100;
    login.pass = req.params.pass, 200;

    var optionsgetmsg = {
      host: 'URL', // here only the domain name
      // (no http/https !)

      path: '/controller/verifica.asp?a=' + login.user + '&b=' + login.pass, // the rest of the url with parameters if needed
      method: 'GET' // do GET
    };


    var reqGet =  https.request(optionsgetmsg,  function (res) {

       res.on('data',  function (d) {
        jsonResponse = JSON.parse(d);
        result = jsonResponse.message;
      });

    });
    reqGet.end();
    reqGet.on('error', function (e) {
      console.error(e);
    });
    context.id = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);
    console.log(result);
    //problem
    if(result == "yes"){
    const rows = await operadores.find(context);

    if (req.params.id) {
      if (rows.length === 1) {
        res.status(200).json(rows[0]);
      } else {
        res.status(404).end();
      }
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(rows);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `if(result = 'yes')` do you really want to assign in this conditional or is this a typo?

Comment: Its a String, I've updated the code

Comment: What do you think this `login.user = req.params.user, 100;` will do ?

Comment: The 'user' parameter in the URL

Comment: The `, 100` is confusing because it will not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a library that does HTTP requests and supports promises, something like [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or refactor your current `https.request` and convert it to a promise, here is an example:

```
function makeRequest({ user, password }) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const options = {
      host: 'URL', 
      path: `/controller/verifica.asp?a=${encodeURIComponent(user)}&b=${encodeURIComponent(pass)}`
      method: 'GET'
    };
    const reqGet = https.request(options, function (res) {
       res.on('data', function (d) {
          result = JSON.parse(d);
          resolve(result.message);
      });

    });
    reqGet.on('error', function (e) {
      reject(e);
    });
    reqGet.end();
  });
}
```

Then you can simply do this:

```
const result = await makeRequest(req.params);
```

I've used some concepts that you may not be familiar with, [**template literal**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and [**object 
destructuring**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter)